# What amount of information is stored $this variable in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-1.2

Can anyone tell me total information stored in $this variable of cakephp ?

I was trying to print $this in one of my controller, it was loading the page for long time and nothing gets as outcome.

Comment: you should post the code to show how you do it.

Comment: I just wrote following lines in add method  of my controller. echo "<pre>"; print_r($this); exit;

Comment: `$this` has nothing to do with cakephp http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: if We print $this in beforfilter method of the controller, it prints information about methods, components , models and bind model related to it for that controller. I m asking does any body know what exact information it contains.

Answer (score 2):

`$this` in PHP is always a reference to the object, where it occurs. Try `print_r()`, or `var_dump()` instead of `print()` and look at the pages source code. Don't believe, what the regular browser shows you.